# No-overlapping edges with positioned nodes

Tags: graphviz, path-finding, dot, overlapping, neato

No-overlapping option (overlap=false) and positioned ("-n2" command-line parameter) are incompatible.

```
strict graph {
  overlap=false;
  1 [label="", xlabel=<<FONT POINT-SIZE="7">1</FONT>>, shape=circle, style=filled, width=0.05, pin=true, pos="120.4,31.1!"];
  2 [label="", labelfontsize="5", xlabel=<<FONT POINT-SIZE="7">2</FONT>>, shape=circle, style=filled, width=0.05, pin=true, pos="73,35.5!"];
  3 [label="", labelfontsize="5", xlabel=<<FONT POINT-SIZE="7">3</FONT>>, shape=circle, style=filled, width=0.05, pin=true, pos="236.2,35.2!"];
  4 [label="", labelfontsize="5", xlabel=<<FONT POINT-SIZE="7">4</FONT>>, shape=circle, style=filled, width=0.05, pin=true, pos="350,100!"];
  5 [label="", labelfontsize="5", xlabel=<<FONT POINT-SIZE="7">5</FONT>>, shape=circle, style=filled, width=0.05, pin=true, pos="350,90!"];
  6 [label="", labelfontsize="5", xlabel=<<FONT POINT-SIZE="7">6</FONT>>, shape=circle, style=filled, width=0.05, pin=true, pos="350,80!"];
  1 -- 4 [arrowhead=none, shape=none];
  2 -- 5 [arrowhead=none, shape=none];
  3 -- 6 [arrowhead=none, shape=none];
}
```

when a execute the folloing command-line:

```
neato -n2 -Tpng -ographviz-overlap-test.png graphviz-overlap-test.dotty
```

I got the following result:

[image: graphviz overlap test dot file]

Do you know alternative solution to produce graph of nodes connected with no-overlapping edge?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

As long as you tell `graphviz` the exact position of the nodes, no chance to avoid overlaps with the code you are using. I have manually exchanged the position of nodes 1 and 2 and this way re-ordered the nodes. I guess you produce the `dotty` file with some other software, that's the culprit.

```
strict graph {
  overlap=false;
  1 [label="", xlabel=<<FONT POINT-SIZE="7">1</FONT>>,
    shape=circle, style=filled, width=0.05, pin=true, pos="73,35.5!"];
    #                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  2 [label="", labelfontsize="5", xlabel=<<FONT POINT-SIZE="7">2</FONT>>,
    shape=circle, style=filled, width=0.05, pin=true, pos="120.4,31.1!"];
    #                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  3 [label="", labelfontsize="5", xlabel=<<FONT POINT-SIZE="7">3</FONT>>, shape=circle, style=filled, width=0.05, pin=true, pos="236.2,35.2!"];
  4 [label="", labelfontsize="5", xlabel=<<FONT POINT-SIZE="7">4</FONT>>, shape=circle, style=filled, width=0.05, pin=true, pos="350,100!"];
  5 [label="", labelfontsize="5", xlabel=<<FONT POINT-SIZE="7">5</FONT>>, shape=circle, style=filled, width=0.05, pin=true, pos="350,90!"];
  6 [label="", labelfontsize="5", xlabel=<<FONT POINT-SIZE="7">6</FONT>>, shape=circle, style=filled, width=0.05, pin=true, pos="350,80!"];
  1 -- 4 [arrowhead=none, shape=none];
  2 -- 5 [arrowhead=none, shape=none];
  3 -- 6 [arrowhead=none, shape=none];
}
```

which produces

[image]